# Relative post date in recent posts list

Tags: php, theme-development, css

I have basically worked on this all night and I realize I am quite stuck.

I have a sidebar in my wordpress theme that displays the most recent posts.
The sidebar looks like this:

[image]

Below each title I want to display the post date in "relative style" e.g "posted two days ago".

I know `<?php echo human_time_diff( get_the_time('U'), current_time('timestamp') ) . ' ago'; ?>` will produce the relative date but I do not know how to implement this in the same code I already have.

I also need to be able to style this date stamp with custom CSS.

**This is the php I have for the sidebar:**

```
<?php
$args = array( 'post_status' => 'publish', 'numberposts' => '30', 'tax_query' => array(
    array(
        'taxonomy' => 'post_format',
        'field' => 'slug',
        'terms' => 'post-format-aside',
        'operator' => 'NOT IN'
        ), 
    array(
        'taxonomy' => 'post_format',
        'field' => 'slug',
        'terms' => 'post-format-image',
        'operator' => 'NOT IN'
        )
    ) );
$recent_posts = wp_get_recent_posts( $args );
foreach( $recent_posts as $recent ){
    echo '<div class="sidebar-entries">';
    echo get_the_post_thumbnail( $recent['ID'], 'sidebar-thumb', array( 'class' => 'sidebar-image' ) );
    echo '<div class="sidebar-entries-title">';
    echo '<a href="' . get_permalink($recent["ID"]) . '">' .   ( __($recent["post_title"])).'</a></div></div> ';

    // echo human_time_diff( get_the_time('U'), current_time('timestamp') ) . ' ago';
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't generate a WP Loop using `wp_get_recent_posts()` so `get_the_time()` won't pull the post date.  The post date is available within the array `wp_get_recent_posts()` returns though: `$recent['post_date']`.  Or you can use the modified date: `$recent['post_modified']`.

This works (tested on my dev site):

```
<?php
$args = array(
    'post_status' => 'publish', 
    'numberposts' => '30', 
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'post_format',
            'field' => 'slug',
            'terms' => 'post-format-aside',
            'operator' => 'NOT IN'
            ), 
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'post_format',
            'field' => 'slug',
            'terms' => 'post-format-image',
            'operator' => 'NOT IN'
            )
        ) 
);
$recent_posts = wp_get_recent_posts( $args );
?>
<div class="sidebar-entries">
<?php 
foreach( $recent_posts as $recent ){        
    echo '<div class="sidebar-entry">';
        echo get_the_post_thumbnail( $recent['ID'], 'sidebar-thumb', array( 'class' => 'sidebar-image' ) );
        echo '<div class="sidebar-entries-title">';
            echo '<a href="' . get_permalink( $recent["ID"] ) . '">' . __( $recent["post_title"] ) . '</a>';
            echo '<span class="posted-on">' . human_time_diff( strtotime( $recent['post_date'] ), current_time('timestamp') ) . ' ago </span>';
        echo '</div>';
    echo '</div>';
}
?>
</div>
```

(A note though, don't just copy/paste code from the Codex.  If you don't need the taxonomy argument in there, don't include it.)

Comment: I am not sure if I completely understand what a taxonomy argument is. I tried to read on it but I didn't quite understand it. This works though. Thanks a lot for the effort!

Answer (score 0):

You can do that by by editing the template-tags.php in the inc directory.

Find:

```
sprintf( '<a class="entry-date" href="%s">%s</a>', esc_url( get_permalink() ), $output_time )
```

Replace:

```
sprintf( '<a class="entry-date" href="%s">%s</a>', esc_url( get_permalink() ), $regular_time )
```

Find:

```
sprintf( '<a class="entry-date" href="%s">%s</a>', esc_url( get_permalink() ), $output_time ),
```

Replace:

```
sprintf( '<a class="entry-date" href="%s">%s</a>', esc_url( get_permalink() ), $regular_time ),
```

Comment: I think maybe my question was badly explained. I don't want to replace all time stamps in relative format, only the date in the sidebar. Also I need to know how to implement this in the code I already have so this is not really an answer but thanks for the info.

Comment: Sorry i am little bit confuse can you explain little more